# Is $f(g(x))=x$ when $f(x)=x^{1/2}$ and $g(x)=x^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Getting a little caught up in notation and second guessing things. Could use a hand. I do think that $f(g(x))=x$, but part of me wants to argue that if you say $x=-4$ then $f(g(x))=4$, not $-4$. 
Edit: Such that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Correct, $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ and $-\sqrt{x^2}=-|x|$...

Comment: @Azovax Do you understand that functions need domains?

Comment: Edit: Such that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Azovax Add that information to the question itself, not as a comment. Also do not use the title as the first line of your question.

Answer (score 4):

$f(g(x))=f(x^2)=\sqrt{x^2}=$ $\mid x \mid$